# Qt Creator Project Build Error

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

I get the following error when building a project in Qt Creator:

```
**error: collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**
```

Below is the compile output

```
**Running build steps for project mw_fe...**

Starting: F:/Qt/2009.04/qt/bin/qmake.exe C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/My Documents/mw_fe/mw_fe.pro -spec win32-g++ -r CONFIG+=release 
Exited with code 0.
Starting: F:/Qt/2009.04/mingw/bin/mingw32-make.exe -w 
mingw32-make: Entering directory `C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/My Documents/mw_fe'
F:/Qt/2009.04/mingw/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/My Documents/mw_fe'
g++ -enable-stdcall-fixup -Wl,-enable-auto-import -Wl,-enable-runtime-pseudo-reloc -Wl,-s -mthreads -Wl -Wl,-subsystem,console -o release\mw_fe.exe release/main.o release/mamewah.o release/moc_mamewah.o -L"f:\Qt\2009.04\qt\lib" -lQtDBus -lQtTest4 -lQtScript4 -lQtXmlPatterns4 -lQtXml4 -lQtGui4 -lQtCore4
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/My Documents/mw_fe'
mingw32-make: Leaving directory `C:/Documents and Settings/Administrator/My Documents/mw_fe'
f:\Qt\2009.04\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lQtDBus
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [release\mw_fe.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
Exited with code 2.
Error while building project mw_fe
When executing build step 'Make'
```

Please help me...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> cannot find -lQtDBus

The [QtDBus](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtdbus.html) module is a **Unix-only library**. In theory it's possible to compile [winDBus](http://sourceforge.net/projects/windbus/) and then QtDBus for Windows. But it's not easy and I'm not sure about MinGW...

Comment: Bingo. The fix is to remove the dbus module from the .pro file. Open it and either remove `dbus` from the `QT +=` line, or add another line reading `QT -= dbus` to the file. kemiisto, could you perhaps edit your answer to include this info?

Comment: @ Mihai Limbasan But what if the project really needs QtDBus?

Comment: @kemiisto: Then it's broken anyway, at the moment there's no reasonable way to get the win32 port of dbus (which is badly outdated) to work with QtDBus...